Does the Storage Size shown inside SharePoint online admin center cover both SharePoint and OneDrive
When we access the SharePoint Online admin center it shows the available storage out of the total size:-

so do the available size and the total size cover both SharePoint sites and OneDrive? or only SharePoint? and is exchange mail box also calculated here?

The amount of storage shown at the top right of the admin center is SharePoint only. As per Microsoft (for most commercial SKUs): Total storage per organization = 1 TB plus 10 GB per license purchased; Not including the OneDrive created for each licensed user. Educational tenants might differ. I manage multiple tenants and it always "1 TB plus 10 GB per license" shown as available at the admin center active sites page.
Onedrive is separate. MS: For most subscription plans, the default storage space for each user's OneDrive is 1 TB. Depending on your plan and the number of licensed users, you can increase this storage up to 5 TB.
References:

SharePoint limits
OneDrive service description


thanks for the great reply and help
